# how can i ignore wrong place names in my node js weather app

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have created a node js localhost weather app it is working perfectly but if i enter wrong city name like **jaipur** is right place name but if i enter **jaipr** then my app will crash and server will close. So how can i solve this and if anyone enter a wrong place name then it will show the error message like
"you have enter a wrong place name".

Here is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home", {cityName:null, date: null, temp:null, description:null, imgUrl:null});
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    let today = new Date();
    let options = {
        weekday : "long",
        day : "numeric",
        month : "long",
    }
    let date = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
    let cityName = req.body.cityName;
    https.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cityName+"&units=metric&appid=apikey", function (resp) {
        resp.on("data", function (data) {
            let weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            let temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            let description = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            let icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
            let imgUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";
            
            res.render("home", {cityName:cityName, date:date, temp:temp +"°C", description:description, imgUrl:imgUrl});
        });
    });
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000!");
});
```

Comment: Check the response?

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch around `JSON.parse()` as that might fail on the response data for an invalid city.

When you access something like: `weatherData.weather[0].description`, you have tot make sure that each part is not null before you access its properties.